# Trying to hide information in JPEG picture using frequency domain FFT steganography but can't get correct output picture after encryption

Tags: c#, .net, fft, frequency, steganography

I'm studying frequency domain steganography. My task is to hide text information in JPEG picture using FFT. I prepared some code in C# which takes a picture, prepares it for FFT algorithm and computes its frequency domain using FFT. Input picture is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Wip.jpg), result of FFT algorithm is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UujpP.png). Then this code gets text message, takes complex value from picture and changes LeastSignificantBit (LSB) of this complex value. After this we have modified frequency domain in [this pucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL99c.png), and as you can see, there is a message from center to right encrypted. But when I try to use IFFT in modified picture, the output of this is just a [white picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmANH.png). So obviously I somehow damage the picture during changing frequency domain. What may be wrong with this code?

The code with detailed comments is below:

```
        // Uploading image
        var image = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile("input.jpg");

        // Find the nearest power of 2 dimensions
        int width = (int)Math.Pow(2, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(image.Width, 2)));
        int height = (int)Math.Pow(2, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(image.Height, 2)));
        // Resize the image to the nearest power of 2 dimensions
        Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(image, width, height);

        // Converting image to grayscale
        Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(resizedImage);

        // Converting image to the ComplexImage
        ComplexImage complexImage = ComplexImage.FromBitmap(grayImage);

        // Applying FFT
        complexImage.ForwardFourierTransform();

        // Saving result of FFT
        complexImage.ToBitmap().Save("fourier.jpg");

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // Converting text message to binary
        string textMessage = "Hello world";
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textMessage);
        BitArray messageBits = new BitArray(messageBytes);

        // Embedding text bits into the frequency domain
        int bitIndex = 0;
        for (int y = complexImage.Height / 2; y < complexImage.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = complexImage.Width / 2; x < complexImage.Width; x++)
            {
                if (bitIndex >= messageBits.Length)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Getting complex value of frequency
                Complex complexValue = complexImage.Data[y, x];

                // Replacing the LSB of the real and imaginary parts with a bit from the message
                complexValue.Re = SetLeastSignificantBit(complexValue.Re, messageBits[bitIndex++]);
                complexValue.Im = SetLeastSignificantBit(complexValue.Im, messageBits[bitIndex++]);

                // Applying new value
                complexImage.Data[y, x] = complexValue;
            }
        }

        // Setting LSB
        static float SetLeastSignificantBit(double value, bool bit)
        {
            int intValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0);
            intValue = bit ? (intValue | 1) : (intValue & ~1);
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue), 0);
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

        complexImage.ToBitmap().Save("fourier222.jpg");

        // Applying IFFT
        complexImage.BackwardFourierTransform();

        complexImage.ToBitmap().Save("output.jpg");
```

Comment: I  don’t know why your picture is white, likely a display issue. But changing the LSB of a `double` is unlikely to affect anything, rounding errors affect that bit strongly. After inverse FFT, you’ll need to round to integers for saving to JPEG, and your secret message (if still there) will be rounded away. Next, JPEG encoding will throw away even more data, and by this time there is a 0% chance that any hints of your message are still there. I honestly think this idea cannot work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the idea of encoding text in JPEG image with FFT you mean?

Comment: JPEG does a lot of damage to an image. It is designed to remove any data you can’t see. You probably want to hide your message in the encoded JPEG stream instead. But then you need to know JPEG very well, start by reading the specs.

Comment: @Cris Luengo okay, I agree that JPEG does a lot of damage to an image. But my idea is that when I change the frequency domain of the picture, I change a small amount of information (22 bytes with "Hello world" message), and even after this changes I can't get at least some piece of input picture, and even if the message would be rounded away, I guess it's necessary to get at least some of the picture to proceed in trying to hide a message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I got to know that it is better not to use LSB approach but to change "null" values of frequency domain and adding or substracting real part of frequency data. "Null" value is real value of `ComplexImage[x, y]` taken from frequency data which is equal zero. In this code I use top left corner to find "null" values. Also while moving through the frequency domain it's better to avoid the middle of frequency domain because it can cause troubles and incorrect encoded data. Some code example for encryption:

```
public static ComplexImage EmbedData(ComplexImage freqDomain, byte[] data)
    {
        ComplexImage modifiedFreqDomain = freqDomain;
        int xCoordinate = 0;
        int yCoordinate = 0;

        if (data.Length * 8 > modifiedFreqDomain.Data.Length)
        {
            throw new Exception("Data too large to embed into the frequency domain");
        }

        int bitIndex = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < data.Length; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                int bit = (data[k] >> i) & 1;
                double realPart = modifiedFreqDomain.Data[xCoordinate, yCoordinate].Re;

                if (bit == 1)
                {
                    realPart += 0.00025;
                }
                else
                {
                    realPart -= 0.00025;
                }

                modifiedFreqDomain.Data[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = new Complex(realPart, modifiedFreqDomain.Data[xCoordinate, yCoordinate].Im);

                yCoordinate += 1;

                if (yCoordinate >= freqDomain.Width / 2.5)
                {
                    yCoordinate = 0;
                    xCoordinate += 1;
                }
                bitIndex++;
            }
        }

        return modifiedFreqDomain;
    }
```

When I use this code for encryption, image may be slightly changed but it is not cricical. Also this algorithm should check for "not-null" values because we can't take data from it. So there is some way to improve this method but basically it works.